# IIS Restart (cannot start any process and call iisreset) from the website itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

```
public static void RestartIIS()
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\iisreset.exe";
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(path);
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to restart the IIS or just the site? a dirty way to do the latter is simply to write a file to the web site.

Comment: It is not working ..is there any solution??

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have administrative permissions to do this; running IIS as administrator is absolutely not recommended!

Rather, I'd suggest that instead of trying to administer the site from itself you work with one of the remote access / remote management tools. Something like the remote administration for IIS is basic but useable: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/.